# PhpStorm - theme colour issues

Tags: ide, phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.2

Having some issues with PhpStorm, I've searched and searched but can't find any useful info online. ( there is info ) but not what I'm looking for.

**The system I'm on & Settings:**

macOS X - 10.13.2
PhpStorm - appearance Darcula
PhpStorm - colour scheme Atom

**The issue:**

I opened PhpStorm the other day, and noticed that the sidebar had changed colour. Attached image. I'm finding it hard to read the text, its not white enough. But I can't find where to change it.

I want to make it white, pretty simple question, but I just can't find where to do it.

Can anyone help? Its hurting my eyes to read it :(

[image]

Comment: This looks like VCS file status. Do you use VCS integration? Anything configured in Preferences | Version Control? Check the colors at Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | File Status - "Deleted" and "Deleted from file system" in particular.

Comment: Spot on! Thanks so much. I had no idea that was doing it!! Thanks again!! Want internet points please reply as answer and i'll mark as answered :)